# How To Git Diff And Then Merge To Remote Other Repo

Tags: git, github

The use case is where I've created repo2 from repo1. I've made updates to repo2. Now I wish to capture the updates made in repo1 since the initial creation. That point is straight forward, run

```
git diff <commit-id>
```

back to the commit ID in repo1 which produced repo2.

The trick I wish to perform, is to merge this diff into the master branch in repo2.

Any tips or ideas on how to achieve this, ideally using git command line would be much appreciated :)

Comment: You can't fetch repo1 from repo2?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a simple diff using `git apply`. However, doing so loses the history and isn't the customary way of handling this.

Generally, one handles this by pushing the repository to a Git server, and then fetching the changes from that location, using `git push` and `git pull` (or `git fetch`). If one of the systems is directly accessible from the other, you can fetch the changes directly from that server or directory with `git pull` or `git fetch`. You'd specify the remote location and the branch you want to merge, such as `git pull https://github.com/git/git.git next` to merge the `next` branch from that URL.

If the systems are disconnected, you can create a bundle file, using `git bundle create`, to create an archive of the repository data, and then copy it to the other machine, using `git pull BUNDLE-FILE BRANCH` to pull in and merge the branch in question from the bundle file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you bk204.

The solution I found was -

```
git remote add temp-branch https://git-domain.net/v1/layer-technical.git
git pull temp-branch master --allow-unrelated-histories
Fix conflicts and then commit the result.
git push
```